# Connecting to MySQL server from Android application

Tags: java, android, mysql, spring-mvc

I am trying now to build an Android application that will connect to a MySQL DB on a web server to collect search, add and update records on DB.

I've read that I can do this using PHP, but I already have a small web application built using Spring MVC, Hibernate that work on the same DB, so I was wondering what is the best way to make the Android application connect and interact with the remote DB?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a Spring MVC app, use an HTTP client from Android to connect to it, send requests that update the DB.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You mean like when saving, updating or searching data, I shall use like HttpClient,HttpPost...etc? Do you think this is the most effective way?

Comment: Do you want to connect directly to the database or use a web application to do it for you? If the former, then yes, HttpClient with HttpPost will work. There are plenty of HTTP clients out there you can use.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If I can use my Spring MVC/ Hibernate web application to connect to the DB from Android, this will be much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to concentrate the Business logic with data access on 1 place. In your case, on your web application you can provide some "webservices" in your MVC application. Like, a controller with actions as a REST web service. This way, all your android application will do is send HTTP requests to your WebApplication.

More on RESTful services using Spring mvc in the documentations: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you should a library to connect to My SQL DB throught HTTP protocol, then add this library into android your application

Comment: _you should a library_ I accidentally a whole bottle.